# React Hooks: defaultValue for textField is null and gives error-Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null

Tags: react-hooks

I have an email textField that defaults to null when no value. The Redux state where it fetched data from is null(which is ok) but when that value is null I want the field to have '' so that the below warning is not thrown

```
Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components.
```

I have a function where, value is read

```
const [emailValue, setEmail] = useInput(email)
```

Hook where value is set

```
const useInput = (defaultValue = '') => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue)

  const handleChange = useCallback(target => {
    setValue(target.value)
  }, [])

  return [value, handleChange]
}

export default useInput
```

I assumed when default value is set to  '' in  `const useInput = (defaultValue = '')`
it would make the value to '' when redux state gives null, but the value is still null and does not become ''
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

if you would like that the default value will be '' then you should replace null with undefined because null it's a value therefor it's not the empty string you expected to be.

Default function parameters allow named parameters to be initialized with default values if **no value or undefined** is passed